# Get value from multiple checkbox's selected and display in TextArea

Tags: java

I will have display all the toppings the user selected and there can be more than one but my code only display one at a time. Please advise.

Here is my code for toppings part:

```
 public String toppingsSelect()
    {
        String toppingsSelectString = "";
        
        if(tomatoCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Tomato";
                
        }
        if(greenPeppersCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Green Peppers";
        }
        if(mushroomsCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Mushrooms";
        }
        if(blackOlivesCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Black Olives";
        }
        if(sausageCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Sausage";
        }
        if(extraCheeseCheckBox.isSelected())
        {
                toppingsSelectString = "Extra Cheese";
        }
        return toppingsSelectString;
    }

displayString =  "Pizza type : " + crustSelect() +      "\n" + 
                         "Pizza size : " + sizeSelect() +     "\n" +        
                         "Toppings   : " + toppingsSelect() +  "\n" +
                         "Amount Due : " + dollarDecimalFormat.format(totalPriceFloat);
        outputTextArea.setText(displayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you assign a value to toppingsSelectString it replace the precedent value. You should put for exemple toppingsSelectString += " " + "Tomato";